# Tailwind - details with the symmetry of my letters

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I want these cards to have the same size and image size, but the margin with the cards ain't the same
[letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku7i2.png) my idea it's put the **continue reading** level with the other letters. and make them level equally

this is the component:

```
<article class="flex flex-col shadow my-4 mx-3 lg:mx-1">
    <!-- Article Image -->
    <a href="{{ route('view', $post) }}" class="hover:opacity-75">
        <img src="{{ $post->getThumbnail() }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}"
            class="object-fill aspect-[4/3] h-min w-full border-t-2 border-b-2 border-l-2 border-r-2 border-purple-700">
    </a>

    <div class="bg-white flex flex-col justify-start p-6">
        <div class="my-2 flex gap-4">
            @foreach ($post->categories as $category)
                <a href="{{ route('by-category', $category) }}"
                    class="text-purple-600 text-sm font-bold uppercase pb-4 font-sans hover:text-purple-700">
                    {{ $category->title }}
                </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>

        <a href="{{ route('view', $post) }}" class="text-3xl font-bold hover:text-gray-700 pb-4">
            {{ $post->title }}
        </a>

        @if ($showAuthor)
            <p class="text-sm pb-3">
                {{ __('By') }} <a href="#"
                    class="font-semibold hover:text-gray-800">{{ $post->user->name }}</a>,
                {{ __('Published on') }}: {{ $post->getFormattedDate() }} | {{ $post->human_read_time }}
            </p>
        @endif

        <p class="pb-6">
            {{ $post->shortBody() }}
        </p>

        <a href="{{ route('view', $post) }}"
            class="uppercase text-fuchsia-600 hover:text-fuchsia-700">{{ __('Continue Reading') }} &nbsp;
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</article>
```

this is the method i use to call

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
            <div class="mx-4">
                <h2
                    class="text-lg sm:text-xl font-bold text-fuchsia-500 uppercase pb-1 border-b-2 border-fuchsia-500 mb-3">
                    {{ __('Category') }}: {{ $category->title }} &nbsp; &nbsp;

                    <a href="{{ route('by-category', $category) }}">
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </h2>

                <div class="mb-6">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-3">
                        @foreach ($category->publishedPosts()->limit(3)->get() as $post)
                            <x-post-item :post="$post" :show-author="false" />
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```